# Tomcat - Can't find datasource for jndi name

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, datasource, jndi

I'm using:

```
Java 1.8.0_112
Tomcat 8.5.6
```

The target machine is Linux but for now I'm running with
NetBeans 8.2 under Windows 7
as with earlier versions in years gone by, it's taking me way too long to get Tomcat configured so that web applications can access a database.

In server.xml I have

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
```

with nested

```
<Resource>
```

expressions (Plural).

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mySchema"
    username="myschema"
    password="xxxxx"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.123.123.123:1522:MYDB"
    initialSize="2"
    maxTotal="20"
    maxIdle="10"
    minIdle="2"
    maxWaitMillis="-1" 
    testWhileIdle="true"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="20000"
    validationQuery="select * from dual" />
```

I am confident that this part is OK because a security Realm which uses a database for authorisation, is/was able to access the schema OK.

A web application tries to make use of those same

```
<Resource>
```

expressions but repeatedly throws:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Can't find datasource for jndi name=jdbc/mySchema
```

The web application config I have is along the lines of:

In the file META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/myWebApp">
  <ResourceLink global="jdbc/mySchema" name="jdbc/mySchema" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

In WEB-INF/web.xml section

```
<web-app>
```

I have multiple resource-ref statements, each something like:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mySchema</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Tomcat documentation:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/site/trunk/docs/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/globalresources.html
makes me wonder if these

```
<resource-ref>
```

expressions are needed because is says they are equivalent to what appears in

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
```

That same page of Tomcat documentation shows:

```
<res-ref-type>
```

where I have got

```
<res-type>
```

I've tried both, either way I get the same exception:

javax.naming.NamingException: Can't find datasource for jndi name=jdbc/mySchema

I've had all this stuff working OK in the past and I've read numerous pages of Tomcat documentation. Sadly none that describes how:

```
<GlobalNamingResources> <Resource> <ResourceLink> <resource-ref>
```

all hang together to avoid "Can't find datasource for jndi name".

**Addition to initial question**

On Jeff's suggestion I've just looked up the code I haven't looked at in years. I have to sheepishly come clean, the text in that exception is our code.

I need to investigate deeper

**Second addition to question**
Sorry to have wasted your time, I was using the wrong jar file. I don't fully understand what was happening, to fix it pulled code from GIT, re-compiled the jar file and all is well.

Comment: It would help to see the Java that is used to get datasource and the entire stack trace.

Comment: Jeff, thank you for waking me up. I've added the code to the question.